# How to discern devices based on their traces?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I would greatly appreciate your advice on following machine learning problem:

I need to train a classifier to learn a device's behavior. The device itself can be observed under different operating/input conditions through a set of sensors. A sensor yields time series data and we call all observations during an interval a trace. More formally, a device is indirectly described through its emited traces of parameters $P$ (each having a domain $D_{P_j}$). A trace is a sequence of observations taken during a certain time interval:

$$ 
T_1 = \{ <t_1, p_1,\dots, p_k>, \; <t_2, p_1,\dots, p_k>, \; \dots \}
$$
$$
...
$$
$$
T_n = \{ <t_i, p_1,..., p_k>, \; <t_{i+1}, p_1,..., p_k>, \; \dots \}
$$

$$
with \; t_x \in \mathbb{R} , \; p_j \in D_{P_j} $$

The set of all traces, i.e., the training data for the machine learning system is $T = \{T_1,...,T_n\}$.

The question is now, how can I construct a machine learning system, that - given a trace $T_q \notin T$ - it can determine, if the trace $T_q$ has been emitted by the trained device or not?

What is the problem class?
What would be an appropriate algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: This seems to be far too broad a question; without knowing any details, the answer is likely "read that textbook".

Comment: The answer I was looking for is "Feature-based Classification of Time based Classification of Time-series Data". Candidates for features of each trace $T_i$ are mean, variance, skewness, kurtosis, and their derivatives. These feature vectors can be the input to some ML algorithm like ANN. Thanks & case closed.

Comment: You might want to consider posting that as an answer (and accepting it) so the platform also knows that the case is closed.